# Select the highest last row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select the highest last row of each member.

```
ID     UID      POINT        DATE           TIME

1       1         5       2012-11-29      11:29:03    
2       2        10       2012-11-29      11:38:12    
3       1        10       2012-12-02      05:15:01    
4       3         5       2012-12-02      09:51:34    
5       2         5       2012-12-02      12:14:14    
6       3         5       2012-12-04      12:18:30
7       1         5       2012-12-05      06:00:51
```

So I want to select the ID, UID and POINT where the point is the higest of each user.
The result should be:

```
ID     UID      POINT        DATE           TIME

2       2        10       2012-11-29      11:38:12    
3       1        10       2012-12-02      05:15:01      
6       3         5       2012-12-04      12:18:30
```

I tried with this:

```
SELECT distinct uid, point, id FROM `test` 
GROUP By uid ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

AND

```
SELECT id, uid, point FROM `test` 
GROUP BY uid ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

But I got the some wrong result:

```
4(3), 2(2), 1(1)
```

Comment: Can you just show your expected results in a proper column ids? isn't the `highest` followed by `max()`?

Comment: I edited the opening post (added: The result should be:...)

Comment: so you need your data to take Date, Time in to consideration?

Comment: I do not want to print out the date and time, but take it consideration if the point is some (e.g: ID 4 and 6)

Comment: Do you prefer any order on the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will select the highest points for each user:

```
select uid, max(`points`)
from members
group by uid
```

and this will select the maximum id where the user has the maximum points:

```
select uid, max(id)
from members
where (uid, `points`) in (select uid, max(`points`)
                          from members
                          group by uid)
group by uid
```

and this is the final query that you need:

```
select members.*
from members
where (uid, id) in (
  select uid, max(id)
  from members
  where (uid, `points`) in (select uid, max(`points`)
                            from members
                            group by uid)
  group by uid)
```

that shows:

```
ID  UID  POINT  DATE        TIME
2   2    10     2012-11-29  11:38:12    
3   1    10     2012-12-02  05:15:01      
6   3    5      2012-12-04  12:18:30
```

this will also give the same result, and looks simpler:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM
  (SELECT members.*
   FROM members
   ORDER BY uid, points desc, id desc) s
GROUP BY uid
```

I think that it will always work, but it's not documented!

A little explanation for the last query: MySql allows you to select nonaggregated fields in a group by query. Here we are grouping by `uid` but selecting all columns: the documentation says that  the values of the nonaggregated columns will be undetermined (it can be **any** value inside the group) but in fact MySql just returns the first encountered value. And since we are applying a group by with nonaggregated columns on an ordered subquery, the first encountered value is what you need.

Comment: it seems to OK after a few name changes

Comment: I like simplicity but it's too simple to work but it looks to work :) Thank you

Comment: @Gery i edited a little my answer, to explain why last query is not documented, and why i believe it will always work!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT id, uid, MAX(point) FROM `test` GROUP BY uid ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
```

Comment: I only get 1 row (but I have 3 user, so should be 3 row): id / uid/ MAX(point) : 4 / 3 / 5 (added: The result should be:... format type in my opening post) OR changing the lmit to 3 is wrong result too)

Comment: Tried query in my post and worked. I did combine DATE & TIME column in a TIMESTAMP column. SELECT id, uid, MAX(point) FROM `test` GROUP BY uid ORDER BY date DESC

Comment: mysql> SELECT id, uid, MAX(point) FROM `test` GROUP BY uid ORDER BY date DESC; result = id 4, uid 3, MAX(point) 5 ; id 2, uid 2, MAX(point) 10 ; id 1, uid 1, MAX(point) 10

Comment: I tried again, but WHERE the UID is 3 I get not the latest row (the point is the same in ID 4 and 6, but I get the ID 4 but the latest inserted row is 6

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT id, uid, point FROM `test` 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY point DESC, date DESC, time DESC
```

Comment: I get wrong result to Where the uid is 3, the ID will be 4 insted of 6

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19ec2/16)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1 
WHERE t1.ID = (SELECT MAX(t3.ID)
               FROM Table1 t3
               WHERE t1.UID=t3.UID
               AND t3.POINT=(SELECT  MAX(t2.POINT)
                               FROM Table1 t2
                               WHERE t2.UID = t3.UID))
```

Result:

```
| ID | UID | POINT |                            DATE |     TIME |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  2 |   2 |    10 | November, 29 2012 00:00:00+0000 | 11:38:12 |
|  3 |   1 |    10 | December, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000 | 05:15:01 |
|  6 |   3 |     5 | December, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000 | 12:18:30 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one:

```
SELECT ID, UID, MAX(POINT) FROM `test` GROUP BY UID ORDER BY DATE DESC, TIME DESC
```

Comment: The same: WHERE the UID is 3 the ID should be 6, because the latest inserted row is 6 (the point is the same)

Answer (score 0):

- [SQLFIDDLE Reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92726/1) : updated from first answer to match expected results.

Query:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT p.*
FROM points p
ORDER BY uid, point desc, id desc) as x
GROUP BY x.uid
;
```

Reusults:

```
ID  UID     POINT   DATE                                TIME
3   1       10      December, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000     January, 01 1970 05:15:01+0000
2   2       10      November, 29 2012 00:00:00+0000     January, 01 1970 11:38:12+0000
6   3       5       December, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000     January, 01 1970 12:18:30+0000
```

Comment: WHERE the UID is 3 the ID should be 6, because the latest inserted row is 6 (the point is the same)

Comment: @Gery just notieced your updated expected results. You are better off with fthiela and justin. +1 for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `points` ORDER BY point DESC) AS `t1` GROUP BY uid;
```

Comment: `order by uid, points desc, id desc` like in my answer is better :) it will work, I use this trick a lot, even if it is not documented

Comment: yeah me too, but haven't been doing any SQL lately.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT max(point), id, uid  FROM test 
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY point DESC

use in this way, it wil solve your problem.